# По какому адресу находится Stack Pointer Register в STM32F407?

Tags: stm32

Stack Pointer находится во Флеш  по адресу 0x08000000
А где находится Stack Pointer Register? Слышал что такой есть, но не видел описание и где он находится.

Comment: Имею подозрение что [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Answer (score 2):

`SP` - это регистр процессора, а регистры не имеют адреса. Поэтому нельзя ответить на вопрос "по какому адресу".

Вместо адреса регистры имеют номер, который записывается в коде инструкции. Если посмотреть в документ ARM Architecture Reference Manual, раздел A8.8.104, то можно найти пример двоичного кодирования инструкции `mov`.

```
------------------------------------------
| F E D C B A   9 8   7  6 5 4 3   2 1 0 |
------------------------------------------
| 0 1 0 0 0 1 | 1 0 | D |   Rm   |  Rd   |
------------------------------------------
```

где Rm - регистр-источник, Rd - регистр назначения.

Регистры `R0`-`R12` кодируются числами от `0` до `С`. Регистры `SP`, `LR`, `PC` кодируются числами `D`, `E`, `F` соответственно. Тогда на ваш вопрос можно ответить - регистр `SP` имеет "адрес" 13.

Взглянув на код инструкции, можно увидеть, что поле `Rm` состоит из 4 бит, а поле `Rd` - из трёх. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что не любой регистр может быть регистром назначения в инструкции `mov`. В документе так и написано: в данной кодировке инструкции этот регистр может быть от `R0` до `R7`.

В памяти процессора ARM Cortex по адресу `0x00000000` должно находиться начальное значение указателя стека. Поэтому компиляторы при линковке записывают в первые 4 байта исполняемого файла требуемое значение указателя стека. Процессор при старте извлекает из своей памяти начальное значение и записывает его в регистр `SP`.

В контроллерах STM32 регион памяти `0x08000000` отображается на `0x00000000`, так что да - по адресу `0x08000000` тоже располагается начальное значение указателя стека.